# Remove embed youtube video title using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I know showinfo parameter is deprecated now. So Is there any other option that I can remove the title of embed youtuve video like jQuery/CSS or any other option. I tried with JQuery as well css but no success. I embed youtube code in iframe.

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; padding-bottom: 56.25%; margin: 0px;"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qHn0SJHL6Sk?rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"></iframe></div>
```

Js I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ytp-title-text').remove();
});
```

CSS

```
.ytp-title-text{ display: none !important;}
```

Comment: First of all you misspelled `important`. You should also show how you have implemented the youtube video.

Comment: @KHansen I update the question pls have a look